# Self canceling events using bind

Tags: javascript, lottie, bodymovin

What I'm looking for here is a method to refer to a bound method from within that method for the purpose of removing an eventlistener from within the event listener.

I'd like to create a single method to handle the same action over a few different events.

I've got a function that handles rotating the elements called `rotateActiveItem`. It looks at a list of list items and activates one at a time.

In my constructor I'd like to set up a few, potentially many, events that trigger `rotateLoadingCopy`.

```
this.oneQuarter = genericDurationEvent.bind(this, animationDuration * .25);
this.half = genericDurationEvent.bind(this, animationDuration * .5);
this.threeQuarters = genericDurationEvent.bind(this, animationDuration * .75);
```

Each of these are added to the animation's events:

```
this.animation_.addEventListener('enterFrame', this.oneQuarter);
this.animation_.addEventListener('enterFrame', this.half);
this.animation_.addEventListener('enterFrame', this.threeQuarters);
```

And then the event checks for duration, executes the rotation, and then should remove itself from the eventListeners.

```
genericDurationEvent(duration, event) {
  if (event.currentTime >= duration) {
    // Activate the next loading text element.
    this.rotateActiveItem();

    // Stop listening for this event.
    this.animation_.removeEventListener('enterFrame', /*What goes here?*/);
  }
}
```

At first I thought maybe I could bind the bound method onto another method, but that's a rabbit hole of bound functions.

Then I thought `arguments.callee` would do this, but I'm in strict mode it its deprecated in strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going for a closure pattern, and generating the handlers dynamically, so you can keep a reference to the function.

```
genericDurationEvent(context, duration) {
  var handler = function (event) {
    if (event.currentTime >= duration) {
      // Activate the next loading text element.
      this.rotateActiveItem();

      // Stop listening for this event.
      this.animation_.removeEventListener('enterFrame', handler);
    }
  }.bind(context);
  return handler;
}

this.oneQuarter = genericDurationEvent(this, animationDuration * .25);
this.half = genericDurationEvent(this, animationDuration * .5);
this.threeQuarters = genericDurationEvent(this, animationDuration * .75);
```

If you wanna go the extra mile, you could isolate the logic in a way that the generator makes any function behave like "once" *ala [jQuery#one()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L83)*:

```
// definition
function once (what, eventName, originalHandler) {
  function onceHandler (...args) {
    what.removeEventListener(eventName, onceHandler);
    return originalHandler.apply(this, args);
  };
  what.addEventListener(eventName, onceHandler);
}

// usage
once(this.animation_, 'enterFrame', event => {
  if (event.currentTime >= animationDuration * .25) {
    // Activate the next loading text element.
    this.rotateActiveItem();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I really like this second pattern. :-)